# Windows: Power save mode: How set screen brightness?

Tags: windows

Win11, Dell XPS laptop

On battery, I want the screen to go to 50% brightness after 2-3 min, and stay there on screen saver for 10 or 15 min, before the screen is turned off.

How to configure this?

Comment: I'm almost sure there is no way to dim the brightness when the screensaver kicks in (or after a set amount of idle time.)

Comment: @YisroelTech Yeah, I have never seen it. I have been living the laptop life more heavily. My screen saver is a series of family pics that I like to always have playing. It has been interesting to experience how weak this area of the OS is. (Even when plugged in, the screen saver trashes pics when an external monitor is used.)